# What are nested projects in eclipse/java

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Can someone provide useful links regarding "nesting of projects",i am asking this question specifcally in context of java/eclipse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In context of eclipse it means that you create a new project and try to create a new project within the first project. As far as I know that's not possible. Check [Top Ten Architectural Problems in Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Top_Ten_Architectural_Problems_in_all_of_Eclipse) for further information.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Eclipse now supports nested projects.

Answer (score 12):

Since Milestone 5 of version 4.5, Eclipse IDE supports nested/hierarchical view of projects: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M5/

Comment: That's finally some good news.

Comment: Note that the nested projects feature works in the Java EE perspective with the project explorer, but does not appear in the Java perspective with the package explorer.  Also, if you have some working sets, then can cause havoc with the feature - making projects vanish in weird ways.

Comment: Indeed. You are free to use the Project Explorer instead of Package Explorer in the perspective if you prefer it.
And indeed, mixing working sets and nested project is currently a bit difficult. It's actually pretty deterministic when one perfectly understands how workingsets work in Project Explorer (as filters and groups), but it doesn't make it simple. If you have ideas on how to improve things, please report to bugs.eclipse.org

Answer (score 0):

As schlingel already said, eclipse can't handle nested project. Generally nested projects represent subprojects or modules of a bigger project and they often inherit settings while the base project might manage the nested ones.

Using Maven and the m2eclipse plugin you might get support for nested projects to some extend. The filesystem representation would be nested, however eclipse can't display that as such. In eclipse they'd look like parallel projects, but the m2eclipse plugin has some support to at least provide some functionality nesting would provide.

Answer (score 0):

One way of grouping projects visually in eclipse are working sets. However, note that working set structure is visual presentation only, it does not create nested projects and it does not effect directory structure (just as schlingel and Thomas said).